# How to Drag and Drop Multiple Elements on a Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a function that let me drag and drop a list of elements into a matrix.

The first step that I am trying right now is to simple drag one element into an area. It do it right on the first element but the second and the others don't.

## Code

I have the next **JavaScript** code:

```
var dragSrcEl = null;

function dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}

function dragEnter(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Entered the dropzone";
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
}

function dragLeave(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Left the dropzone";
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
}

function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

And the **HTML** is using this by doing the next code:

```
...
            <div class="input-group input-group-option col-xs-12" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">1</span>
              <input type="text" name="option[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Focus me">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
              </span>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group input-group-option col-xs-12" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">2</span>
              <input type="text" name="option[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Focus me">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
              </span>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group input-group-option col-xs-12" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">3</span>
              <input type="text" name="option[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Focus me">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
...
```

How can I Drag and Drop more then one element?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FMCalisto/rmcmypv1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try this one:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    if (ev.target.childNodes.length === 0) {
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }    
}
```

Demo below here:

[DEMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427673/drag-and-drop-multiple-items-html5)

[DEMO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010591/how-to-drag-and-drop-multiple-elements-between-different-tabs)

Comment: I try your solution but the behavior is worst that it was, now I can drag the element but even the first element can't be drop.